# javascript or jquery popup to display target url in same page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, popup

How to open javascript or jquery popup to display target url in same page
either using jquery or javascript
can anyone please provide me with a link i have searched on google but was unable to found a valuable thing

Comment: **POP** and and **in the same window**. its confusing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some markup..

```
<a href="http://www.somesite.com"> Some Site Link </a>

<div id="popup"> This is the popup text pre $.load() </div>
```

Here's some code...

```
$('#popup').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true
});

$('a').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#popup').load($(this).prop('href'), function(){
        $('#popup').dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Comment: The code above might not load somesite.com on the dialog since: "Due to browser security restrictions, most "Ajax" requests are subject to the same origin policy; the request can not successfully retrieve data from a different domain, subdomain, or protocol." http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: TechyTimo The previous is a valid comment and should be considered carefully when building your jQuery application.

Answer (score 0):

Just use following things

```
<script>
  $("#target").load("your link");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say you already make the popup appear on click of a link or a button so call a function on onClick event and pass the target url as a parameter. the in that function you can use alert like

```
alert(url);
```

and then use 
`window.location = url;`
 to redirect the page.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented highslide js and it is working fine...
Thanks fellows